# How do I set the time zone in Trac?

Tags: timezone, trac

I am struggling with setting up time zones with Trac. I have searched around but I have found nothing helpful. What can I do?

Both a whole site timezone or a per-user timezone settings would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default timezone for whole site is set up in the `trac.ini`:

```
[trac]
default_timezone = ...
```

In user preferences you have date time preferences (*`«base_url»`*`/prefs/datetime`), where user can set his own (per user) timezone.

See for example http://trac.edgewall.org/prefs/localization

Answer (score 5):

Like indicated by others, the solution is to add this to trac.ini:

```
[trac]
default_timezone = ...
```

But the tricky thing is the formatting (see http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/9581):

- you can either use `GMT +xx:xx` format (simple but not time saving aware)
- or enter a timezone name e.g. `America/Los_Angeles` which requires [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) to be installed - see http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/PyTz.

Answer (score 0):

To set the site default timezone, edit `trac.ini` with the following syntax:

```
[trac]
default_timezone = GMT +10:00
```

or

```
[trac]
default_timezone = GMT -7:00
```

Comment: I recommend using format "Region/City", because this takes care of daylight saving changes. In vartex answer has the list of available options.